# AOP integration with AXON framework

Tags: aop, axon

I am using axonframework 2.3.1 , for unit testing the application there is a **Aggregate class** which contain some event handlers. now i want that before inovking the commandhandler method contained in the Aggregate class i want to apply aop tracing @Before and @After those handler methods.
I am using FixtureConfiguration interface and apply newGivenWhenThenFixture to the aggregate class,As the wiring of the axon configured classes is done by axon framework.
 I have configured the aop configuration in another xml file and i load that xml file before running the test cases.How can i integrate the aop tracing with the axon wired aggregate class.

Thanks

I used this example at http://www.axonframework.org/axon-2-quickstart-guide/#step1 in this example i want that i should be able to log before/after trace messages for  `class ToDoEventHandler`  every method called.

Below is similar code where i have written some aggregates and aspect to configure.
I have one aggregate class

```
    public class ToDoItem extends AbstractAnnotatedAggregateRoot{

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;

     @CommandHandler
        public ToDoItem(CreateToDoItemCommand command) {
            apply(new ToDoItemCreatedEvent(command.getToDoId(), command.getDescription()));
    }
    @CommandHandler
    public void markCompleted(MarkCompletedCommand command){
        apply(new ToDoItemCompletedEvent(id));      
    }
    public ToDoItem(){

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void on(ToDoItemCreatedEvent event){
        this.id=event.getTodoid();
    }

}
```

and one EventHandler class

```
    public class ToDoEventHandler {

    @EventHandler
    public void handle(ToDoItemCreatedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("We are starting a task: "
                + event.getDescription() + " (" + event.getTodoid() + ")");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void handle(ToDoItemCompletedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("We've completed a task: " + event.getTodoid());
    }

}
```

the configuration file spring-axon as follows

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:axon="http://www.axonframework.org/schema/core"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.axonframework.org/schema/core http://www.axonframework.org/schema/axon-core-2.0.xsd">

<axon:command-bus id="commandBus" />
<axon:event-bus id="eventBus" />

<axon:event-sourcing-repository id="toDoRepository"
    aggregate-type="com.my.axon.ToDoItem" />

<axon:aggregate-command-handler id="toDoItemHandler"
    aggregate-type="com.my.axon.ToDoItem" repository="toDoRepository"
    command-bus="commandBus" />

<axon:filesystem-event-store id="eventStore"
    base-dir="events" />


<bean
    class="org.axonframework.commandhandling.gateway.CommandGatewayFactoryBean">
    <property name="commandBus" ref="commandBus" />
</bean>

<axon:annotation-config />
<bean class="com.my.axon.ToDoEventHandler" />

<bean class="com.my.axon.AopConfigurator"></bean>
```

now i want that before/after ToDoEventHandler class  every method called i should be able to log before and after aspects so i created an aspect and configured it.

```
/**
 * This class is used to configure the AOP related beans 
 * instead of doing the entries the beans are configured here and the
 * same effect is achieved using @EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation. 
 * @author anand.kadhi
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AopConfigurator {

    @Bean
    public AspectRunner aspectOperation()
    {
        return new AspectRunner();
    }   
}
```

and aspect

```
    @Aspect 
    public class AspectRunner {

        /**
         * This pointcut will call respective before and after method execution 
         * points
         */
        @Pointcut("execution(* com.my.axon.ToDoEventHandler.*(..))")
        public void logging(){};

        @Before("logging()")
        public void entering(JoinPoint joinPoint)
        {

            System.out.println("After completing Class : "+joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName() +" and method : "+joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        }

        @After("logging()")
        public void exiting(JoinPoint joinPoint)
        {
            System.out.println("After completing Class : "+joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName() +" and method : "+joinPoint.getSignature().getName());


        }
    }
```

and there is a main class

```
public class ToDoItemRunner {

private CommandGateway commandGateway;

public ToDoItemRunner(CommandGateway commandGateway) {
    this.commandGateway = commandGateway;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-axon.xml");
    ToDoItemRunner runner = new ToDoItemRunner(applicationContext.getBean(CommandGateway.class));
    runner.run();
}

private void run() {
    final String itemId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    commandGateway.send(new CreateToDoItemCommand(itemId, "Need to do this"));
    commandGateway.send(new MarkCompletedCommand(itemId));
}
```

}

*I want that before/after ToDoEventHandler class  every method called i should be able to log before and after aspects .*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is StackOverflow. Please provide code and configuration as a basis for discussion, not just plain prose. Ideally, show us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), maybe from a GitHub repo.

Comment: Thanks **kriegaex** for advice i will post the code

Comment: Still confused by your question. You say your *aggregate* had event handlers but it is actually a separate event handler class (not the aggregate) you want to weave with your aspect?  Also you say this has something to do with given when then test fixtures, but I don't see the fixture? (The fixture doesn't use Spring nor separate event handlers so certainly won't work for this)0, but I think that's moot)

Comment: I use built-in Spring aspects like @Transactional all the time, so are you sure your point cuts are working?